# Get unique values and their amounts from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

So I get a JSON request that sends an array of objects with two properties, I need to extract the unique values and their quantities.

This is the JSON that is being sent via Postman:

```
[
    {"name": "First value", "amount": 2},
    {"name": "Second value", "amount": 4},
    {"name": "First value", "amount": 6}  
]
```

I need to return a JSON response with the unique values and their totals added up:

The object should look like this:

```
{
   "First value": 8,
   "Second value": 4
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
const arr = [ 
    {"name": "First value", "amount": 2},
    {"name": "Second value", "amount": 4},
    {"name": "First value", "amount": 6}  
]

const res = arr.reduce((ac, {name, amount}) => {
  ac[name] = ac[name] || 0;
  ac[name] += amount;
  return ac;
},{})

console.log(res)
```

#### Explanation:

First of all we are initializing `ac` to an empty object `{}`. See the line

```
arr.reduce((ac, {name, amount}) => {...}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The highlighted part is called Object destructuring. It will get the property `name` and `amount` out the current object through which we are iterating and make it independent variables.

See the line

```
ac[name] = ac[name] || 0;
```

Now this line is checking if `ac[name]` doesn't exist on the `ac` object then it will be `undefined` so `undefined || 0` will be evaluate to `0`. If it will have a value the value of `ac[name]` will remain as previous.

See the third line:

```
ac[name] += amount;
```

This line will add the `amount` to already value of `ac[name]`

At last we return `ac` so that it will be become initial value of `ac` for next iteration.

Comment: Works wonderfully, however, could you elaborate a bit more in how does the accumulator work there? I don't quite understand it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great response. Much simpler than the madness I was coming up with.

Comment: @Scarecrowsama Do you understand how `reduce()` works generally or you don't understand `reduce()` at all.

Comment: I understand the basics with numbers, but this object creation is a bit confusing, I am guessing than the line ac[name] is basically like doing {name:} without the value, I know that when you send a form, the body is an object and you can access to it like that object[property] o object.property right?

Comment: @Scarecrowsama I have added an explanation ask if you don't understand anything. Consider accepting the answer if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as it is for the most part easier to understand and follow:

```js
let arr = [{ "name": "First value", "amount": 2 }, { "name": "Second value", "amount": 4 }, { "name": "First value", "amount": 6 } ],
    obj={}

arr.forEach(({name, amount}) => {
  obj[name] = obj[name] || 0
  obj[name] += amount
})

console.log(obj)
```

The main difference here is that our `accumulator` (the `obj`) is defined outside rather than "internally" as an argument to the `Array.reduce` function.